# mklivestatus compile issue

Tags: centos, nagios

i am trying to integrate nagios with mklivestatus and during the compilation of livestatus.o module, it fails, i have installed all the packages which are required according to the documentation.

output of rpm -qa on my centos 5.6 box:

```
libstdc++-4.1.2-50.el5
libstdc++-4.1.2-50.el5
libstdc++-devel-4.1.2-50.el5
make-3.81-3.el5
gcc-4.1.2-50.el5
libgcc-4.1.2-50.el5
gcc-c++-4.1.2-50.el5
libgcc-4.1.2-50.el5
```

i have attached the full log of mklivestatus here

http://chopapp.com/#erojbw91

any ideas why the install fails

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the development tools installed, I'm not sure if there are additional packages missing from your list, but from a quick search, you should be able to do the following:

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

You might also try looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643197/missing-include-bits-cconfig-h-when-cross-compiling-64-bit-program-on-32-bit) other answer on issues building applications on x64 platforms.